# Bulk update in Oracle12c

Tags: oracle, performance

I have a situation like to update a column(all rows) in a table having 150 million records.

Creation of duplicate table with updates and dropping of previous table is the best way but there is no available disk space to hold the duplicate table.
So how to perform the update in less time? Partitions are there on the table.
I am using oracle 12c

Comment: Show us the update you want to run.

Comment: Is this a new column you want to populate, or an existing column you want to amend? Is the updated value derived from columns on this table, or do you need to get values from other tables?

Comment: for an existing column i have to mask the characters like substr(column_name,1,5)||'XXXX'@APC

Comment: "Less time" without providing any reference doesn't help. Wouldn't it still faster just to use whatever way you're doing it now than waiting for answers?

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest approach is NOT updating the table, but creating a new table with the new column of updated rows.  For instance, let's say I needed to update a column called `old_value` with the max of some value, instead of updating the old_table one does:

```
create new_table as select foo, bar, max(old_value) from old_table; 
drop table old_table; 
rename new_table as old_table.
```

If you need even more speed, you can do this creation using a parallel query with nologging thereby generating very little redo and no undo logs. More details can be ascertained here: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:6407993912330

Comment: i am aware of this technique but space is not available to store the new table.@gregory

Comment: @siva if you have so little space, then you may end up running out of space for the undo. Storage space is cheap, so I would encourage you to re-evaluate Gregory's suggestion.

Comment: If your table is partitioned, maybe you can recreate the table partition at a time.

Comment: How about compressing the old table: alter table old_table move compress;

Comment: Hi gregory thanks for your suggestions,does a normal user can perform compress operation.i don't have DBA  access

Comment: @siva No, it typically takes elevated rights that only a DBA would have.

Comment: because of space constraint,i thought to go with creation of new table and inserting one partition and deleting the same partition from the old table,if i iterate the same procedure for all partitions will it work normally.or may have any impacts

Comment: @siva, yep, this is a viable option.